# GEE export raster with value for no-data

Tags: javascript, libgee

When I open an exported image from GEE in Qgis, I see that the no data has no value and is shown as n/a. I would to know if there is a way to export the image from GEE with a value already assigned for no-data and that value being recognized as no-data in Qgis.

I can assign the no-data value in Qgis without a problem, but it would be more efficient to do it inside GEE. The only way I found so far is to unmask the image and give a value, but when I open the image in Qgis, that value is not recognized as no-data and is shown as a regular value.

Is it possible to do this in GEE?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the `formatOptions: {noData: noDataVal}` argument, as expressed [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-todrive). Below is a summary of the code available at the hyperlink.

```
// A Landsat 8 surface reflectance image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2/LC08_044034_20210508')
  .select(['SR_B.']);  // reflectance bands

// A region of interest.
var region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.24, 37.13, -122.11, 37.20);

// Define a nodata value and replace masked pixels with it using "unmask".
// Set the "sameFootprint" parameter as "false" to include pixels outside of the
// image geometry in the unmasking operation.
var noDataVal = -9999;
Map.addLayer(image)
var unmaskedImage = image.unmask({value: noDataVal, sameFootprint: false});
// Use the "noData" key in the "formatOptions" parameter to set the nodata value
// (GeoTIFF format only).
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: unmaskedImage,
  description: 'image_export_nodata',
  folder: 'ee_demos',
  region: image.geometry(),  // full image bounds
  scale: 2000,  // large scale for minimal demo
  crs: 'EPSG:5070',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    noData: noDataVal
  }
});
```